# How to cache for high cardinality keys (composite keys) and low/fixed cardinality data

Tags: caching, memcached, system-design

I am trying to design for a use case where we have high cardinaltiy keys and low/fixed cardinality data.

The high cardinality of keys(multiple millions) results from them being composite keys e.g.

keys like:

```
product:location:time
```

The data itself is low/fixed cardinality (let's say 2 million items)

I want to use composite keys so that we have low latency lookup at run-time (rather than doing joins at run-time)

let's say each key has about 500 items.

What's the best way to cache data like this? Is it better to do online filtering i.e. have the secondary keys as metadata and then filtering in real time? or, is it better to just scale the cache horizontally to accommodate for all the possible composite keys?

As you can see, adding a secondary key will lead to combinatorial explosion of keys in the cache.

I think there's no right answer(balancing act) but looking for creative ways to design this.

Solutions/Papers around this appreciated